# Delete blank lines in a tab delimited file

Tags: csv

I have a tab delimited file which has a few lines with no data in them, however there are tabs in those empty records. For example when I do `cat -vet file.csv`, the output comes as

> col1^Icol12^Icol3^Icol4^Icol5^Icol6^Icol7$
>   acb^Ibad^Iaso^Icna^Isoc^Iioe^Ifhn$
>   soc^Iioe^Ifhn^Iacb^Ibad^Iaso^Iaso$
>  
>   ^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
>   soc^Iioe^Ifhn^Iacb^Ibad^Iaso^Iaso$

I am looking for a output as

> col1^Icol12^Icol3^Icol4^Icol5^Icol6^Icol7$
>   acb^Ibad^Iaso^Icna^Isoc^Iioe^Ifhn$
>   soc^Iioe^Ifhn^Iacb^Ibad^Iaso^Iaso$
>  
>   soc^Iioe^Ifhn^Iacb^Ibad^Iaso^Iaso$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is probably to use `grep` to filter out all the lines containing only whitespace:

```
grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a quick program that would read all the lines in, removing any that were blank, and write them back out. This way you have a file with no blank lines.

In C#

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("FilePath").Where(x => x.Trim() != "");
File.WriteAllLines("FIlePath",lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to discard all lines with less than, say, 10 characters:

```
grep -E '^.{10,}$' inp.csv
```

Depending on your specific situation you might need to adjust the threshold for short lines to discard.